# Azure service bus messaging with Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, azure, sdk

Currently my team is very frustrated with Azure Service Bus messaging and finding the right clients / protocols on Android and iOS.

Service Bus supports amqp 1.0 protocol. Are there clients for android and iOS to handle amqp 1.0?

What are the other options for listening for queue messages?

Are there any sample apps that listen for messages from Azure service bus on Android and/or iOS? (that are not from 2013 and actually are working/compiling)

---

Side info (not strictly related to the question):

The problems we came across were:

- It really is true: the azure team primary focus is on microsoft technologies, mostly Windows Phone 8 and Xamarin for Android and iOS.
- Documentation: A wonderland of scattered topics sometimes having an example for android, sometimes xamarin android, sometimes ios or xamarin.

Comment: Hi, I don't think that Azure team primary focus on MS technologies (but I'm Microsoft MVP so it seems to be as part of MS ;-)) ... However, you can access Service Bus using AMQP 1.0 and HTTP (RESTful APIs) that aren't MS related technologies. Speaking about Android I think you can use Qpid Proton (http://qpid.apache.org/proton/) in the Java version but for iOS I think that the only way is to use HTTP. Of course if you develop in native code without using Xamarin.

Answer (score 3):

After almost 80 hours of investigation, google and trial and error I found the solution to send `BrokeredMessages` from Xamarin. The following code works:

```
    private const String topic = "mytopic";
    private const String keyName = "RootManageSharedAccessKey";
    private const String sharedAccessKey = "myAccessKey";
    private const String baseAddress = "myaddress.servicebus.windows.net";

    private async static void SendMessage(String baseAddress, string queueName, string body)
    {
        string fullAddress = $"{baseAddress}{queueName}/messages";
        HttpClient client = Program.CreateHttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("BrokerProperties", @"{ ""MessageId"": """ + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + @"""}");

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractSerializer s = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string));
        XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(stream);
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        s.WriteStartObject(writer, body);
        s.WriteObjectContent(writer, body);
        s.WriteEndObject(writer);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        var response = await client.PostAsync(fullAddress, new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(new System.IO.MemoryStream(stream.ToArray())));
    }

    private static HttpClient CreateHttpClient()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8");
        string token = GetSASToken(baseAddress, Program.keyName, Program.sharedAccessKey);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", token);

        return client;
    }

    private static string GetSASToken(string baseAddress, string SASKeyName, string SASKeyValue)
    {
        TimeSpan fromEpochStart = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        string expiry = Convert.ToString((int)fromEpochStart.TotalSeconds + 3600);
        string stringToSign = WebUtility.UrlEncode(baseAddress) + "\n" + expiry;

        HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SASKeyValue));
        string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));

        string sasToken = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}",
              WebUtility.UrlEncode(baseAddress), WebUtility.UrlEncode(signature), expiry, SASKeyName);
        return sasToken;
    }
```

Mention that using async await it is very important to do

```
new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(new System.IO.MemoryStream(stream.ToArray()))
```

Otherwise the `PostAsync` will block until the timeout occurs. I am not absolutely sure why. I guess the `MemoryStream` is somehow closed or disposed and the sync `Context` of await blocks the `PostAsync` call.

Comment: Can you please add your imports/usings to the code?

Comment: No problem to put the shared access key in your xamarin application (which is subject to be reverse engineered by someone to grab your key) ?

Comment: Putting login data in the Xamarin-App-Source is a big "nono". In the sample this is done for the sake of ease. For a possible secure solution you can e.g. use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android

Comment: Is there any solution available for Native iOS Apps?  Not with Xamarin.iOS.